# Add an assignment in a loop but cost extra 50% time in JAVA

Tags: java, loops

I have a loop like this（`q = 20000`, `m = n = 200`, actually different `k` has different arrays of `qx`, `qy`, `dx`, `dy`. But I didn't post all code here）:

```
double[][] ED = new double[n][m];
for(int k = 0; k < q; k++)
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   ED[i][j] = dis(qx[i], qy[i], dx[j], dy[j]);
```

This loop cost about `5s`.

"dis" is a function to calculate the distance between `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. Don't mind it.
The problem is  when I add another assignment in the loop just like this:

```
double[][] ED = new double[n][m];
boolean[][] bool = new boolean[n][m];
for(int k = 0; k < q; k++)
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   {
     ED[i][j] = dis(qx[i], qy[i], dx[j], dy[j]);
     bool[i][j] = ED[i][j] > 5000;
   }
```

I want to know whether the `ED[i][j]` is larger than 5000,so do a simple compare. But the new version code cost about 8s to run. I think it is impossible to cost so much time. But I try many ways and fail to find where the problem is. I hope somebody can help me. Thank you very much. The code is incomplete here, but I promise I do nothing but add a simple sentence. Even if I add a `bool[i][j] = true;`, it cost extra `1.5s`.

Comment: You aren't using `k` in either version, remove the outer loop and your performance should improve.

Comment: How large are `q,n,m` ? Also we can much better help you if we are able to reproduce the issue. Please try and post a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: q is almost 20000, n and m is near 200

Comment: Why do you have a loop over `k`?

Comment: Thank you, I re-edit the question know. actually different k has different array of qx,qy,dx,dy. But I didn't post all codes here.

Comment: You're doing 200 * 200 * 20,000 = 800,000,000 2D array accesses, integer comparisons, and boolean storages to memory. That can't be free.

Answer (score 1):

Since k=2000 m=n=200, the inner loop i.e.

```
ED[i][j]=dis(qx[i], qy[i], dx[j], dy[j]);
bool[i][j]=ED[i][j]>5000;
```

This will be repeated nearly 2000×200×200 = 80000000 times! In so many iterations, even a simple array check or Boolean assignment will cost a lot of time.

Comment: But if i just repeat a simple 80000000 times loop( qx,qy,dx,xy nerver change by k) , new boolean assignnent cost nearly 0. Only in my origin code the problem occur.

Comment: @Mark.zxx Well, this isn't simple assignment. You're referencing two different arrays each time. Then assigning a value to another 2D array. Simple Boolean assignments are cheap but here you are using 2D arrays which need to be checked each time the loop iterates.